# Oozie - Java action - does not capture values on System.exit(1)

Tags: hadoop2, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I have a Java action running in an Oozie workflow. Inside the Java program, I set Oozie properties. When I do a graceful exit (`System.exit(0)`), these values are available in the Oozie workflow using `${wf:actionData('action_name')['key']}`. However, when I do an exit indicating error (`System.exit(1)`), the values are null.

Is this a known bug / feature?

Comment: AFAIK, for Oozie, a failure is a failure is a failure. Why bother to collect the output, which may be incomplete/corrupt/meaningless out of context??

Comment: So you will have to manage a specific key for "success" or "status", and never use `System.exit()` -- _for the record, in older versions of Oozie, even `exit(0)` would trigger an error status, so you had to let the `main` class terminate implicitly..._ -- then add a Decision action to manage the success/failure at application level.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have a singleton ExceptionHandler class in my Java program, that I use to catch all exceptions. I map a key (say, `Error`) to the stack trace of the exception, and then access this value in the workflow so I can mail the stack trace to myself using an `email` action. It makes sense to exit with a `System.exit(1)` when there is an exception, instead of with a `System.exit(0)`, which is the hacky workaround I'm currently using.

Comment: _"It makes sense to exit with a `System.exit(1)` when there is an exception"_ >> clearly it makes sense to **you**, not to the Oozie developers _[a Yahoo! team in India, in majority]_. Either you follow their logic, or you use another scheduler. End of story.